# Something is over riding my Custom CSS in my Main CSS. (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Here is my CSS code for my Wordpress site. (I couldn't paste here as it was too long.)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mu0wy9kvhvxrd9k/style%20%282%29.css?dl=0

I would like to change the font size of this, this has paragraph tags within. How do I change it? I am using wordpress and I can add custom CSS to fix this.

Here is my wordpress site that I am trying to fix using Inspect Element in Chrome and Firebug in Firefox. http://defensionem.com/2015/09/14/us-military-demo-3/

```
<div class="body-text clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
```

I tried using this, but no avail.

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"]
 {font-size:32px;}
```

I read this is correct and something seems to be over riding it my main CSS file. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"] p {
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

The font size is being applied to the div. But the paragraph are not inheriting the font-size. You need to explicitly assign the css to paragraphs.

[image]

Comment: It is a bad practice to link your CSS styles to attributes. You should not mix semantics (`itemprop` attribute) and style in your code. It leads you to producing stinky and unmanageable and unsupportable code.

Answer (score 2):

In the CSS, the `font-size` is set on the `<p>` element, you will need to add it also on the same element to override.

Change your CSS to

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"] p {
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

Comment: This was spot on. This works like a charm. Important above works too by using the <p> element.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably already set, try this:

```
div[itemprop="articleBody"]{
  font-size:32px !important; // adding !important forces the style
}
```

I will stress using `!important` is not a good thing - sometimes necessary though

Comment: `!important`should only ever be used for debugging purposes, *never* for production code.

Comment: @connexo why?? is that can you explain it to me

Comment: In an ideal world @connexo yeah I agree... depends on whether you're writing everything from scratch... sometimes you might need brute force

Comment: In that case, you always find and fix the reason you need brute force.